# How to use amplify-flutter without cli

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

Our client provided required Cognito User Pool id and related tokens but not giving the aws credentials so is there any possibility to setup aws amplify official flutter library with out using cli?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to modify the CFN file see

aws-export.js
and
the cloudformation temlpate basicauthentication5fbc10de-cloudformation-tempalte.yml

in [this solution](https://github.com/dabit3/full-stack-serverless-code/tree/master/basic-authentication) for an idea how to do this.